# Unity3d Accessing Gameobject Function And Return String Value

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I have two scripts; Localization.cs and LocalizeText.cs. I'm trying to access Localization.cs from LocalizeText.cs. When I access the GetLocalString() function, I receive an error. The error says :

> "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object Localization.GetLocalString (Int32 menuId) (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Localization.cs:162) LocalizeText.Awake () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/LocalizeText.cs:46)"

I'm accessing Localization.cs from LocalizeText.cs using Getcomponent<>. Could you help me please.

Thank you for your time.

> Localization.cs Script :

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JsonFx.Json;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Localization : MonoBehaviour {
public TextAsset LanguageFile;
private List<Language> _languages ;

private enum Languages
{
    Turkish = 0,
    English = 1,
    German = 2,
    French = 3,
    Russian = 4,
    Portuguese = 5,
    Spanish = 6
}

private void Awake()
{        
    _languages = new List<Language>(JsonReader.Deserialize<Language[]>(LanguageFile.text));
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Language", 0);
    Debug.Log(GetLocalString(6));//it works
}



public string GetLocalString(int menuId)
{
    string value = _languages[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Language")].menu.MenuStrings[Convert.ToInt32(menuId)];
    return value;
}

public class Language
{
    public int LanguageId;
    public Menu menu;
    public Language()
    {
        menu = new Menu();
    }        
}

public class Menu
{
    public List<string> MenuStrings;

    public Menu()
    {
        MenuStrings = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

}

> LocalizaText.cs Script :

```
  using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class LocalizeText : MonoBehaviour {

private Text _text;
private Localization _localization;

public enum MenuItems
{
    Start = 0,
    Garage = 1,
    WatchVideo = 2,
    TiltControl = 3,
    GamePadControl = 4,
    Yes = 5,
    Continue = 6,
    CityRoad = 7,
    SnowyRoad = 8,
    Ridgeway = 9,
    MainMenu = 10,
    Exit = 11,
    Speed = 12,
    Acceleration = 13,
    Brake = 14,
    Play = 15,
    Loading = 16,
    LeaderBoard = 17,
    Quests = 18,
    Achivements = 19,
    No = 20,
    AreYouSure = 21

}

public MenuItems MenuItemStrings;

private void Awake()
{
    _text = GetComponent<Text>();
    _localization = GameObject.Find("Localization").GetComponent<Localization>();
    Debug.Log(_localization);
    Debug.Log(_localization.GetLocalString(System.Convert.ToInt32(MenuItemStrings)));
}
```

}

> Output :
>   [image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private List<Language> _languages;` gets filled in the `Awake` method, and the other script tries to access it also in an `Awake` method. So what happens when the Script trying to access a language from the list has it's `Awake` method run first? Before the method to populate the list?

It gets a `NullReferenceException`.

So try either throwing the accessing block into the `Start` method, and if that doesn't work, then theres either something wrong with the json parsing, or the key just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ill assume what  ***LOLslowSTi***  said its the problem, you have both methods in `Awake`.
You can change it to `Start` as he said. Or you can change the `script execution order`.

Documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html